# Error sending email when I click on a link in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

This is the link I am clicking on

```
<a href="mailto:hr@xyz.com?subject=Job Id:USA_OH_01_2012 Location:Ohio,USA Post  Applied  For: Android Developer">Android Developer, USA. </a>
```

I got the message unsupported action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to configure a google or some other mail account to be able to send an e-mail from the emulator. You can do this by clicking on the gmail app on the emulator and configuring your gmail account with the emulator. This will allow you to send the email.

Comment: can you tell me step by step process to configure my gmail account

Comment: I configured my gmail account and it works fine after that..thanx Dinesh for your help.